# get field from Record Types in Coq

Tags: coq, coq-tactic, coqide

I am new to Coq.
I have a record type and one definition:

```
Record t : Type := T {
  width           : nat;
}.

Definition indent shift f :=
  match f with
  | T w => T
    (w + shift)
  end.
```

I want to proof a trivial lemma:

```
Lemma lemma :
  forall (a:t) n, width a <= width (indent n a).
```

after unfolding `indent` subgoal becomes:

```
(width a <= width match a with
                   | {| width := w |} => {| width := w + n |}
                   end)
```

How to simplify term?

Answer (score 0):

destruct a. simpl.

After that induction.

Comment: Using `induction` is incorrect here; the `Nat.le_add_r` lemma should be used or at worst, you should call some arithmetic procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Use a different definition and `simpl` will do the work:

```
Definition indent shift f := T (f.(width) + shift).
```

Answer (score 0):

When you see a term with `match a with ... end` in it, you can simplify it by doing `destruct a`.  Also if you need to get rid of  `let a := b in ...`  If you need to remember what `a` was, do `destruct a eqn:Ha`.